# Android App Lock

Tags: android, lockscreen

I'm attempting to apply a lock screen for my app.

I thought process is if the password is incorrect go page A and if its correct go to page B.

I'v written this

```
int PIN = R.id.Txt_password;
int pass = 4444;
if (PIN == pass) {


    //Selecting the button which is to be pressed
    Button Btn_Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn_Submit);
    //Creates a listener for the button to react when it is pressed
    Btn_Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //Gives the button instructions when it is pressed
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Control_Screen.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);

        }
    });
} else {
    //Selecting the button which is to be pressed
    Button Btn_Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn_Submit);
    //Creates a listener for the button to react when it is pressed
    Btn_Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //Gives the button instructions when it is pressed
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Password.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

which has failed.

This is the code for Txt_password

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/Txt_password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Lbl_EnterPassword"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="4444" />
```

I'm thinking the password is 4444 which is hard coded in but iv got a feeling that that isn't the case and there is the issue.

How would I go about making this right?

Maybe there is a way to place the text which the user enters into the password field into a string?

Comment: You do realize that goes you are attempting to implement this does not offer any security benefit? Aside from the fact that it doesn't work...

Comment: Thanks. For the moment i'm just learning how to things. Security is a job for later on in the project. Again thanks for the advise.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not fetching the text of your `EditText`. You can get it by doing:

```
EditText passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Txt_password);
int PASS = Integer.parseInt(passwordText.getText().toString());
```

And now do the comparison.

```
int pass = 4444;

if(pass == PASS) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

But, you need to do this inside the `onClickListener` of your button. See the reference code below:

```
Button Btn_Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn_Submit);

    //Creates a listener for the button to react when it is pressed
    Btn_Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //Gives the button instructions when it is pressed
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Txt_password);
            int pass = Integer.parseInt(passwordText.getText().toString());

            if(pass == 4444) {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Control_Screen.class);
                startActivity(startIntent);
            }
            else {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Password.class);
                startActivity(startIntent);
    });
```

Comment: This solution takes me to the control page regardless of the password being correct or incorrect. am I right in thinking it might be my if statement? All other solutions take me to the password incorrect page.

Also I was not me who marked these answers as a down vote.

Comment: This has sorted my problem out perfectly. Thanks for your assistance. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant to do this?

```
EditText txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Txt_password);
int PIN = Integer.parseInt(txtPassword.getText().toString());

if (PIN == 4444) { }
```

`R.id.Txt_password` will never equal `4444`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the text from the EditText field and change it to integer value, like this:

```
EditText passText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Txt_password);
int PIN = Integer.valueOf(passText.getText().toString());

if (PIN == 4444) { 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off going the other way around. Don't change the whole button listener, and don't create anonymous objects inside the method call. How about separating the binding from your actual business logic? Consider this:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button Btn_Submit;
    private EditText Txt_password;

    private final PIN = 4444;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // inflate layout of fragment or set content if this is an activity
        (...)

        Btn_Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn_Submit);
        Btn_Submit.setOnClickListener(this);

        Txt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Txt_password);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // if you have multiple elements with click listeners in this fragment/activity, separate calls here. I'm assuming we get only the submit button here.

        Integer input_pin = Integer.parseInt(Txt_password.getText());
        if (PIN == input_pin) {
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Control_Screen.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
        }
        // if pin wrong, reset text field and optionally show the user a notification
        Txt_password.setText("");
    }
}
```

If you wanted to make it even more clean, put the whole code from onClick into a method called `onSubmitPin()` and call it from onClick when the submit button was pressed.